# Xcode: How to add new tab screen in IOS5 storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

[image]

I have this..
How do I add another tab screen using iOS5 storyboard, so that "Account" can have 3 screens.

Account ---> Account Listing ---> Account Details

Comment: u can have a tool bar with 3 buttons, each have individual views

Comment: What about using a paged scroll view?

Comment: Check this site out. I think it will help you. Tab controls are about 1/3 of the way down the page. [Beginning Storyboards in iOS5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

Comment: @Vishy, there is already 4 tabs, but i want 2 extra view screens for the account tab.

Answer (score 50):

You first drop in a new ViewController, and then you Ctrl-drag from the Tab Bar Controller to that new controller.

This brings up a popup where you can select "Add Relationship Segue". This connects it as a third tab.

Comment: To add to the above answer - when you add it in Storyboard, you probably want to add an image via storyboard (even as a placeholder). If you do not add an image, the bottom bar may turn 'grey' and may hide the other tabs images when viewed in Storyboard...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done **programmatically**:

```
// Tab Controller
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

// Views to be accessed
UIViewController *controllerOne = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController *controllerTwo = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UIViewController *controllerThree = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

// Store UIViewControllers in array
NSArray* screenControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controllerOne, controllerTwo, controllerThree, nil];

// Add Views to Controller
tabBarController.viewControllers = screenControllers;
```

Or using **InterfaceBuilder**:

- Adding 'Tab Bar Items' to the hierarchy of views in the left-hand panel

  [image]

Or using **Storyboard**:

[iOS Storyboards](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) (Scroll down/Search for '*Just Add It To My Tab*')

Comment: I recommend you use the programmatic approach.  There are other programmatic ways to do it, I would definitely recommend any of them over using InterfaceBuilder for this task.  Do some research into which approach you prefer.

Comment: how do you do it in iOS5 story board?